# Location of HHVM Config File

Tags: hhvm

I have built hhvm from source code. but I can not configure hhvm-fastcgi. I could not find ini file for configuration.

HHvm binary is located at **/usr/local/bin**. I wanna run hhvm with nginx. My purpose is adding custom php extension to hhvm. The source code at **/home/vagrant/dev/hhvm**. My operation system is Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my default ini file. Have a try to creating it.

```
file is /etc/hhvm/server.ini






; php options
pid = /var/run/hhvm/pid
; hhvm specific 
hhvm.server.port = 9001
hhvm.server.type = fastcgi
hhvm.server.default_document = index.php
hhvm.log.level = Warning
hhvm.log.always_log_unhandled_exceptions = true
hhvm.log.runtime_error_reporting_level = 8191
hhvm.log.use_log_file = true
hhvm.log.file = /var/log/hhvm/error.log
hhvm.repo.central.path = /var/run/hhvm/hhvm.hhbc
hhvm.mysql.typed_results = false


hhvm.debug.full_backtrace = true
hhvm.debug.server_stack_trace = true
hhvm.debug.server_error_message = true
hhvm.debug.translate_source = true
```